# how can i call talib macd in c++?

Tags: c++, ta-lib

i can use talib MACD function correctly in python, but it failed in c++.

talib is easy to use in python, i can use it as:

```
MACD(close, 12, 26,9) # close is a pandas series
```

but when i use it in c++, it confuses me about the params.

I have a function which update one close price for one time, so i save the close price sequence in a vector, like this:

```
std::vector<double> close_price;
void f(double new_close) {
  close_price.push_back(new_close);
  std::vector<TA_Real> a(655360, 0.0);
  std::vector<TA_Real> b(655360, 0.0);
  std::vector<TA_Real> c(655360, 0.0);
  int s, n;
  TA_RetCode retCode = TA_MACD(0, close_price.size(), close_price.data(), 3, 12, 1, &s, &n, a.data(), b.data(), c.data());
  assert(retCode == TA_SUCCESS);
}
```

but it always failed in assert, ERROR message is:

```
Error 5119(TA_INTERNAL_ERROR): Unexpected Internal Error - Contact TA-Lib.org
```

did i miss anything? i think i passin the parameters as the example talib provide.

Comment: You may like to post the entire error message verbatim to help people help you. That Python code version is unrelated and irrelevant.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thanks, error message added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`endIdx` is the last index, not the size. Hence, you need to call it as:

```
TA_MACD(..., close_price.size() - 1, ...);
```

Comment: @xyhuang Well, my answer fixes one error present in your question.

Comment: @xyhuang The code is working and return `TA_SUCCESS` on my machine. Probably you didn't add something in your example that really reflects the processing. Also, I would insist on calling in `int main(...) { if ( TA_Initialize() != TA_SUCCESS) return -1;  <... app code...> return TA_Shutdown(); }` This library initialiser is crucial for come candle indicators and must be called always on library load/unload.

Comment: @xyhuang Apart from that if you are looking into indicator calculation each time new data value arrives (`f(double new_close)`) you may better to check out [TA-Lib RT](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt) - a fork designed for that purpose.